# In 16.04 has symlinks changed in how to create them?

Tags: 16.04, symbolic-link

I installed 16.04 for arm and all old symlinks previously created on 14.04 were fine. But I tried to create a soft link in 16.04 the same way I did in 14.04 and the link points back to itself in a never ending loop.
Tried various permissions on folders and various locations.
I also used winscp to create a link through that interface.
All had the same outcome.

Is there something extra or changed in this version?

Link syntax used:

```
ln -s /path link-name
```

Comment: Symlinks have not changed; my guess is you are using a relative path not a full path which can lead to recursiveness like this.  What was the full command you wrote?

Comment: I tried both full path and relative path. As well as using winscp which never had issues in 14.04, I forget the actual paths I tried offhand as it was many things I tried and that system has been wiped and reverted to 14.04 since. I was curious as to this weird cause as I would prefer to upgrade ultimately.

Comment: Ok found a script I use commonly and grabbed my link line from it:

cores_location='/cores/'

ln -s $cores_location'core_log' /var/www/html/core_log


This works flawlessly in 14.04 as well as Raspbian

Comment: @DanH, try reinstall it using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils`